# What are the different Eclipse Paho C Libraries

Tags: c, paho

I've been searching for the answer to this question but so far have come up dry.

I am building the Eclipse Paho C and C++ libraries. I followed the directions to build the C library using CMake. Because I don't want to distribute the shared libraries to our target machines, I intend to statically link, so I added the flags for that.

```
cmake -DPAHO_WITH_SSL=TRUE -DPAHO_BUILD_DOCUMENTATION=TRUE -DPAHO_BUILD_STATIC=TRUE ../paho.mqtt.c
make
```

This produces the shared libraries as well as four static libraries:

```
./src/libpaho-mqtt3cs-static.a
./src/libpaho-mqtt3a-static.a
./src/libpaho-mqtt3c-static.a
./src/libpaho-mqtt3as-static.a
```

The contents appear to be the same list of files, but lengths are different, so I presume they are compiled with different options. Clearly one would only link against one library, but I'm not sure what the differences are, so I'm not sure which one to use.

I am guessing that the combinations are:

- Synchronous vs. Asynchronous
- SSL vs. no SSL?

If those guesses are correct, then perhaps the a vs. c is async vs. sync (not sure why a c, but whatever), and the ones ending in s.a are the SSL versions. But i'm only guessing.

Does someone definitively know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I found my answer. This is from the README from downloading the Darwin prebuilt binaries. I didn't find it in the other readmes.

- libmqttv3a.so - asynchronous
- libmqttv3as.so - asynchronous with SSL
- libmqttv3c.so - "classic" / synchronous
- libmqttv3cs.so - "classic" / synchronous with SSL

So my guesses were correct.

Comment: Thanks! Just encountered this myself. Except it seems that "static" is no longer part of the filename, unless it was eliminated because I ONLY built static... "Linking C static library src/libpaho-mqtt3c.a"